# HTML Form positioning

Tags: html, css

I have created two HTML form elements, I need them to be placed in the same line but one from is placed below the other.

How can I solve this problem? What CSS i have to apply?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the style `display:inline` to the forms. Forms are block level elements by default and so need to be set to inline. Alternatively you could float the forms.

Answer (score 0):

if it is two text boxes in a seperate \div\

then write like this

```
div.el{display:inline;}
```

Then apply the `class="el"` in each \div\

For simplify the code you can write the css property to \input\ element also.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are block by default and block automatically take 100% of the width available and are pushed one under the other. Inline element simply add next to each other following the flow of the page.

This [article](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) is very well written. It might help you a lot. Here is what you can try to force the form in the page to show as inline element :

```
 form { dispaly:inline; }
```